# Intel Cedarview graphic driver Ubuntu 12.04 on Netbook Acer Aspire One D270

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-netbook, acer

I've tried to install ubuntu 12.10 but it was very slow and was not working properly. I decided to install the 12.04 version and is working fine. Now there is the Intel Cedarview graphic driver available and I was wondering if I should activate it or not or more specifically, if anyone has tested it and if it is working fine? It says: "This driver is required to fully utilise the 3D potential of some Intel Cedarview cards, as well as provide 2D acceleration of newer cards."

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's true! I'm having an Asus X101CH with Intel Atom N2600, and every time I'm reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04, I'm installing the Cedarview driver for HDMI coverage and screen proper resolution